# Alternative strings.xml is mandatory?

Tags: android

I have the followint structure of my Android project

```
res/values/strings.xml
res/values/arrays.xml
```

and language specific

```
res/values-en-rUS/arrays.xml
```

(notice that I do not have `strings.xml` in `en-rUS` folder)

When I run Android lint on my project, it returns an error because I do not have language keys defined in `en-rUS` folder, though it is permitted according to [this doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

**UPDATE**: the question is, what should I do in order to have my project compiled without errors? Should I just re-configure LINT to show these errors as warnings and that's it? Is this the right way to proceed?

Comment: Marcin Orlowski, updated my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not mandatory. It's just a *warning* that you have some set of resources defined for the default locale, and some others for `en-rUS`. As long as all of the resources that are defined for `en-rUS` are *also* defined for the default locale, your app will not crash due to a missing resource. If, on the other hand, you define resources for `en-rUS` that you *haven't* defined for the default locale, and at runtime you request those resources in any locale *other* than `en-rUS`, your app will throw a resource `NotFoundException`, or perhaps some other crash/error depending on how you're trying to use the missing resource. Lint is just trying to warn you.

As Niek said in the comments of this answer, you can [customize the severity level](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html) that lint assigns, changing it from an error to warning, if even ignoring it.

Comment: In addition, if it gives you an *error* now, you can indeed change it to a *warning*.

Comment: " It's just a warning that you have some set of resources defined" - the point is that by default it's an error, not a warning. So my question was if it is the right way to change severity level to warning or there is some other _proper_ workaround instead. Now I see that there's probably not